# CUDA cuInit: Unknown CUDA error value | Blender with Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, nvidia, blender

I use Blender on Google Colab to render my blender files and it used to work fine up until last week.
I didn't change my scripts, the drivers and CUDA version have not changed but now I get the following error when I try to get the devices. Any other command that gets devices also gives the same error.

```
>>> bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.refresh_devices()
CUDA cuInit: Unknown CUDA error value
```

This command was executed in a blender python console:

```
/content# sudo ./blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/blender -b --python-console
Blender 3.0.1 (hash dc2d18018171 built 2022-01-26 00:40:57)
Python 3.9.7 (default, Oct 11 2021, 10:06:01)
[GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

I have been using Colab to render blender files for months now, with different GPUs every time and it used to work just fine. I would reiterate that I made no changes to my scripts since my last successful render.

Here are outputs of some commands that might help:

```
/content# nvidia-smi
Fri Jun  3 10:38:24 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    26W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have checked in the logs and can confirm that the `Driver Version` and `CUDA Version` given above have not changed since my last working execution.

```
/content# nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

```
/content# cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 19:00:34 UTC 2020
GCC version:  Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some discrepancy in the drivers. I managed to solve it.
remove all the Nvidia drivers and then reinstall:

```bash
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

remember to run the blender commands using `sudo` and OPTIX doesn't work anymore, only CUDA.